# Non-transactional jmsTemplate waits for session end

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-transactions

I would like to have jms messages sent by `jmsTemplate.send()` delivered immediately and not after the transaction ends.

I have tried setting `isSessionTransacted` to `false` but it does not help. Despite `jmsTemplate.send(...)` is executed, I do not see it reflected in a broker.

My setup:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    //
    template.setSessionTransacted(false);
    // messages are ack-ed with message.acknowledge()
    template.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return template;
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new 
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUsername, brokerPassword, brokerURL);
    factory.setTransactedIndividualAck(true);
    factory.setAlwaysSyncSend(true);
    factory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(false);
    factory.setUseCompression(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, jmsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    factory.setTransactionManager(null);
    return factory;
}
```

Is there any way to force jmsTemplate to send the messages immediately?
I am using ActiveMQ and Spring Boot 2.

When a message comes, I do the following:

```
@JmsListener
public void test(...) {
  processRequest(...) // process request here
  message.acknowledge();
  jmsTemplate.send(...)  // send response
  // some transaction handling
}
```

```
 sender                                       receiver
   +                                             +
   |                                             |
   |                                             |
+--+--+ +---------------------------------->  +--+--+  
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |          not sent immediately         |     |
|     | <-----------------------------------+ |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       |     |
|     |                                       +--+--+
|     |                                          |
|     |                                          |
|     |                                          |
+-----+                                          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution / workaround**

I made it working by using MessageProducer directly:

```
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
messageProducer.send(createResponse(message, outgoingEntity, session));
session.commit();
messageProducer.close();
```